# Thickness of lines in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

Using `Thickness` in `Graphics3D`, I can't achieve variable thicknesses below 0.01- they are always treated as a thin line with the same thickness. How do I get this to work?

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[{Thickness[0.002 i], Line[{{i, 0, 0}, {i, 1, 0}}]},
  {i, 10}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I remember this coming up before. I think there is an absolute limit to how small the thickness can be. Try `Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[.0000001], 
  Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}}]}]`  help says `The absolute thickness is measured in units of printer's points, equal before magnification to  1/72 of an inch.` googling around it says `The size of the point has varied throughout the history of printing. Since the 18th century, the point's size has varied from 0.18 to 0.4 millimeters.`

Comment: `AbsoluteThickness` has the same effect. I just found out that this bug happens in version 11 but not version 12